# Ошибка "Приложение не установлено"

Tags: android-sdk, android

Тестировал приложение на устройстве, все было гуд. Для тестирования покупок загрузил подписанный апк в Google Developer Console в альфа канал. Добавил покупки. Добавил аккаунты для тестирования. В телефоне под ним залогинен. Для тестирования удалил предыдущую установку приложения, закинул подписанный апк на флешку и запустил установку. Выдает ошибку "Приложение не установлено" в чем может  проблема?. Телефон перезагружал, память чистил, пытаюсь сбросить до заводских настроек, телефон просто перезагружается. Прошивка кастомная.

**UPD**

В списках приложений после удаления приложение все равно есть, только указано что оно удалено

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В новых версиях Android при включённом аккаунте "гостя", приложения обычным методом не удаляются ("удаляясь" только для активного пользователя). Поэтому, при попытке установки приложения(ранее "удалённого") она заканчивается неудачей (ведь на самом деле оно на аппарате уже стоит).

По крайней мере у меня на 5.1. Оставляйте одного пользователя, если используете аппарат для отладки приложений.

Comment: Действительно. Удалил аккаунт гостя и приложение стало отлично удаляться. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотя для проблемы работает рецепт "adb uninstall packageName", теперь хотя бы понятно, почему именно так происходит.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка с установкой решилась удалением приложения через adb, командой adb uninstall packageName

Comment: Спасибо, рецепт работает )