# Проблемы с генерированием апк

Tags: java, android, android-studio, отладка

На устройстве занимался отладкой приложения. Затем удалил его. Сгенирировал АПК в студии и скинул на устройство. При установке получаю следующее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?

Comment: Удалить приложение, а после установить. Либо подписать тем же сертификатом.

Comment: AppStore в андроид приложении? Вы серьезно?)))

Comment: Попробуйте сделать Clean -> Rebuild и переустановить заново.

Comment: Есть ещё такие нюансы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445485/11515, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653541/11515